# Changing Production database using Migration Script in MVC Codefirst

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first

I Have Developed a Web project using MVC 3 CodeFirst Approach and VS2010.After several Months I need to Change DataBase Schema(of course without loosing Data)After searching the web I found migrations which Enable Me to generate change script which seems to work well on local machine.**But My Question is How can i use this script on production server?
Or Any Other Solution for Modifying MSSQL database on production server**.

Comment: You can automatically apply the migrations using the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion Initializer. It will automatically update the database when the application runs for the first time. Some useful info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: thnks @Mez but I have already read That article , It offers producing an script as i said in my question ,the problem is how to use That script on server, But i havent used this Initializer and i am afraid of loosing data, are you sure or have you tested it?

Comment: You don't need a "script" with DbMigrations. The script is the code generated in C# when you add a new migration. What the initialiser does, is simply apply the changes to the database when the initialiser is run. I've never had any issues with doing this in the past, if you're doing it for the first time, I suggest backing up your production db first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark Mentioned , using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion Initializer we can Update Our Database . and it worked for me.